# Sench EXTJs documentation is down, would anyone have an offline version?

Tags: extjs, documentation

Sorry for the non-technical question, but is anyone be able to help me find an offline version of docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1 ?

Best

Comment: You can find [here](http://docs.sencha.com/downloads/extjs-621-docs.zip)

Comment: You may have to make that an early lunch break, and/or enjoy the summer weather, until the docs are available again. At least that's what I do.

Comment: Best way is that you can either take it from friend OR you can just trial and error on available method writing them on console(bcoz their code is having proper documentation which helps us to understand).

Comment: @Alexander or wait till autumn. I'm also in need of offline docs. Would someone please share .zip.

Comment: @nikita Yes, please share your copy of the zip, please.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download & install Zeal. (https://zealdocs.org/)
2. Tools -> Docsets -> Available -> Choose ExtJS
3. Wait for 10 minutes to download
4. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

You can find offline doc [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.VTypes.html#method-email)

[image]
Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you but the link is down, which is my problem